# Analog of $(a+b)^2 \leq 2(a^2 + b^2)$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Is there an inequality such as
$$(a+b)^2 \leq 2(a^2 + b^2)$$
for higher powers of $k$
$$(a+b)^k \leq C(a^k + b^k)?$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [generalized mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality) states that
$$\dfrac{a+b}2\leq \left(\dfrac{a^k+b^k}2\right)^{1/k},$$
with equality if and only if $a=b$, from which it follows that
$$(a+b)^k\leq 2^{k-1}(a^k+b^k),$$
with equality if and only if $a=b$. Thus $C=2^{k-1}$ works and no smaller $C$ works.

Answer (score 12):

Take the ratio $$f(a, b)=\frac{(a+b)^k}{a^k+b^k}$$and observe that it is homogeneous of degree zero, that is $f(a, b)=f(\lambda a, \lambda b)$ for all $\lambda >0$. So $f$ is constant along rays in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so, in particular, 
$$f(a, b)\le \max_{(x, y)\in \mathbb{S}^1} f(x, y),$$
where $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the unit circle. This means that the sought inequality is true with $C=\max_{\mathbb{S}^1} f(x,y)$. You can check that with $k=2$ you recover $C=2$.

Comment: Too pretty man. +1

Answer (score -2):

The first inequality is true because : $2ab ≤ a^2+b^2$

There is no specific inequality for higher powers of k, although you can always give a very higher value for 'C' to make the second inequality true.

Comment: Yes. I have tried with $C=2^k$ and it seems it doesn`t work.

Comment: C doesn't take any specific value. If you want to force the inequality to be correct, you can always give a very high value for 'C'.

Comment: I just noticed that $C = 2^{k-1}$ works (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215472/how-to-prove-abk-leq-2k-1-akbk?rq=1).

Comment: It seems that $c=2^k$ should work as Samuel stated it above, my intuition seems to be good but it looks that I have failed with calculations.

Comment: @hannah You see, I was writing my comment when you was writing yours, I see now that it works.