# Show for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$ that $C_1(1+x^2)^s \le (1+x)^{2s} \le C_2 (1+x^2)^s$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x \in  \mathbb{R}$, then for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$ we must show that there exist $C_1,C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $$C_1(1+x^2)^s \le (1+x)^{2s} \le C_2 (1+x^2)^s.$$

It seems pretty obvious for the case where $s \in \mathbb{N}$, but after playing with it for a while, I don't seem to be getting anywhere for the general case.

Comment: Try studying the quantity $$\frac{(1+x)^2}{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: This was asked very recently (and answered) with a mistake in the exponents (corrected in the answer).

Comment: For some reason that never occurred to me, thanks! I think it's time to get some sleep.

Comment: Here's some discussion on this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/341621/8157 (This question coincides with the other upon setting $x=\frac{a}{b}$)