# Explain this inequality in PDEs, Elliptic Operators (Folland)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am reading Gerald Follands Introduction To PDEs, and I got to this part:

[image]

The part in red is a bit confusing, I am not sure how it follows from the sentences afterwards. I get that both are non-zero and homogenous, which means that we can somehow "standardize" the sum, but I am not sure how this follows for general alpha.

Comment: [Here's a toy model](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/341630/8157) of the same computation.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you! So are you saying that the expression (for simplicity assume the $a_{\alpha}$ to be constants) 

$$ |\xi|^k  / \sum a_{\alpha} \xi^{\alpha} $$

is homogenous of degree $0$, so that it is constant along rays, and so is determined by its maximum on the unit circle?

Comment: The a_alpha ARE constant. The relevant variable here is $\xi$. So yes, that's what the book suggests to do

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I see now, thank you! There is later a comment on this identity, that it is possible to show that there are $R,K$ such that for $\xi$ such that $|\xi| > R$ there is a $K$ such that $| \sum a_{\alpha} \xi^{\alpha} | \geq K|\xi|^m$ This feels like a trivial restatement of the first estimate, since it holds for all $\xi$. Am I missing something there?

Comment: What is m? Surely something smaller than k, right?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Sorry, I meant $k$ of course.( I cant edit the post now)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't overthink that.