# Prove that $|a+b|^p \leq 2^p \{ |a|^p +|b|^p \}$

Tags: inequality

For any real numbers $a$ and $b$ and $1 \leq p < \infty$, prove that

$$|a+b|^p \leq 2^p \{ |a|^p +|b|^p \}$$

This inequality is given in the the book Real Analysis by Royden, Chapter $7$, page $136$. I don't understand how the author comes to this inequality. Can anyone provide some hints?

Comment: At the moment, this question is closed as a duplicate of [How to prove $|a+b|^k \leq 2^{k-1} (|a|^k+|b|^k)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/215472) Although the other inequality implies this one, I do not think they are duplicates - this question is much simpler.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It can be quite simple: let $c=\max\{|a|,|b|\}$ so that
$$
|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|\leq 2c\implies |a+b|^p\leq (2c)^p=2^p(c^p)\leq 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p).
$$
In fact, you only need $p\geq 0$.

---

**Edit**: As Winther indicates [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1184791/136641) in this thread, $p\geq 1$ gives you a stronger result. I'll give a proof using the convexity of a different function than one he suggests. Let $g(x)=x^p$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ and $m=|a|$ and $n=|b|$. We would like to prove $|a+b|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^p+|b|^p)$. By the triangle inequality above, it suffices to show
\begin{align*}
(m+n)^p\leq 2^{p-1}(m^p+n^p)&\iff\left(\frac{1}{2}m+\frac{1}{2}n\right)^p\leq\frac{1}{2}m^p+\frac{1}{2}n^p\\
&\iff g\left(\frac{1}{2}m+\frac{1}{2}n\right)\leq\frac{1}{2}g(m)+\frac{1}{2}g(n)
\end{align*}
which is true due to the convexity of $g$. It is here that we need $p\geq 1$.

Answer (score 13):

Hint:

A [convex function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) always satisfy $$f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y),~~~~~~~t\in[0,1]$$

Take $f(x) = |x|^p$, show that this is convex for $p\geq 1$ (for example by the [second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test#Concavity_test)) and find a suitable value for $t$.

This gives the slightly better inequality: $|a+b|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^p + |b|^p)$.