# Is it true that $|x-y|^n \leq n(|x|^n+ |y|^n)$?

Tags: inequality

In a lecture note, the author states an inequality without proof. Now, to prove the inequality in his note, one could just prove that

$$|x-y|^n \leq n(|x|^n+ |y|^n)$$

My question is then, is this inequality true? And if so, how to prove it?

The lecture note presented the following inequality
The inequality is the following for $+\infty>p\geq 1$:
$$
d^p_W(\mu, \nu) = \inf_{\gamma \in \prod(\mu,\nu)} \int_{X \times X} |x-y|^pd\gamma(x,y)
\leq p \inf_{\gamma \prod(\mu,\nu)}\int_{X \times X} |x|^p + |y|^p d\gamma (x,y)
$$

If the first inequality is not true, than how come is the inequality above true?

Comment: I believe the correct form should be [$|x-y|^n \le 2^n(|x|^n + |y|^n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184781/)

Comment: Are there conditions on $p$? E.g. Which $L_p$ are you working in? $1 \leq p \leq 2$?

Comment: Sorry, yeas. $1\leq p < \infty$

Comment: $|x-y|^{n} \leq 2^{n-1} (|x|^{n}+|y|^{n})$ is also true.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is not true.
Take $ x = 1, y = -1, n = 3$ then we have $ 2^3 \leq 3(1+1)$.

---

It might help for you to state the original inequality.

Comment: Thanks. I just added the original inequality. Perhaps you can help with it.