# Show that for all $a, b \in \mathbb R$, $m \geq 0$, $|a+b|^m<2^m(|a|^m+|b|^m)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I tried using the triangle inequality, I tried using mathematical induction, Bernoulli inequality… but to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $|a + b|^m \le (2\max(|a|, |b|))^m$.

Comment: Here you go: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184781/prove-that-abp-leq-2p-ap-bp